# Reconciling BAR descriptors QNX IDE

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Hello Everybody,
                I am importing a sample project "Bucket-list" from Github https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/next/bucketlist in QNX IDE  but not able to import successfully . Getting error[image: Reconciling BAR descriptors] .
Please have a look on Screen-Shoot and suggest me , what I will have to do for sort -out  the issue.

All suggestions are welcome and appreciated

Comment: Try to delete the previous "bucketlist" project from project explorer (also tick a checkbox "delete project contents on disk"), then try to import it again with a clean tree. Just imported the latest source code and it worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
May be the issue is related to QNXIDE-Workspace setting , sometimes QNXIDE-Workspace setting changed ,Workspace setting reset is the most preferable solution in this way  
I Follow some simple steps to sort-out the issue :-
1. Close QNX IDE
2. Remove .metadata folder that exist in BB10 Worspace
3. Restart QNX IDE & import the Sample project now it's compile & run fine
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after updating to the latest SDK.  Applications worked properly before.  Event clean projects "died" trying to compile BAR.

You can tell something is wrong by right clicking on the package, going to Properties, and selecting Actionscript Build Packaging > BlackBerry

To be clear, the instructions above about the .metadata folder is correct.

Open Explorer, go to C:\users\%username%\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\

(orwhever the user folder is for your IDE) and rename the .metadata to old.metadata.

Restart IDE